# How to get the actual hotstring typed with capitalization in AutoHotKey?

Tags: autohotkey

I am using hotstrings in AutoHotKey and the output is reliant on if characters are capitalized. Is there a way to determine if characters in the keys typed that triggered the hotkey are capitalized? I tried using A_ThisHotkey, but it does not seem to be case sensitive. Please let me know if you have a solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a built in way to do this, but maybe you'd be fine with just creating more hotstrings and using the [`C` option](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm#C) for case sensitivity like this:

```
:C:hello::
:C:Hello::
:C:HeLLo::
:C:HELLO::
    MsgBox, % A_ThisHotkey
return
```

---

Example request from comments:

```
hotstrings := "hello,HELLO,HeLlo,HellO,hElLo,hellO"
for each, hotstring in StrSplit(hotstrings, ",")
    Hotstring(":CB0*?:" hotstring, Func("MyFunction"))
return

MyFunction()
{
    MsgBox, % "Hotstring triggered!`n" A_ThisHotkey
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out, but I have thousands of hotstrings so something like that would not be feasible. I think I’ll just end up using something similar to a keylogger.

Comment: I see. Well you could automatically generate the hotstrings by using the [`Hotstring()` function](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Hotstring.htm) so it'd be more feasible.

Comment: Do you mind providing an example of what you mean?

Comment: Sure, I added one now. So that creates all the hotstrings separated by `,` that are in the string `hotstrings`.

Comment: Thanks. That example clears things up. However, that way means that my average word would have around 100 combinations of upper case and lower case letters, and in this case hello would have 32 combinations. I'm not sure exactly how AHK works with the computer to detect hotstrings, but maybe you do. Do you think that it is more efficient to use a keylogger and look for capital letters in the last word or use about 60,000 hotstrings with an average of 100 combinations each, totaling to 6 million hotstrings.

Comment: Haha, well that does sound like quite a lot. Didn't expect that. I don't know what would be the best approach. Not sure what happens if you create 6 millions hotstrings, maybe it'll be completely fine, maybe it'll be a disaster. Worth a try I guess.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll give them both a try and see what works best. I'll let you know incase you're curious and incase anyone else is trying something similar.

Comment: Yeah I'm interested, be sure to let me know what happens.

Answer (score 1):

You can activate the [case sensitivity option](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm#Options) before defining your Hotstrings

```
#Hotstring c
::Hello::Hi ; will be triggered only if you exactly typed these letters case-sensitive
```